# How to estimate the training input in google cloud ml?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api

I am using the google cloud ml to train a model to detect my custom object by using Tensorflow's Object detection API. By following [this tensorflow's guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md), and read [this google cloud ml's docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview), I configured my training input and saved in `cloud.yml` as follow:

```
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.2"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerCount: 5
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerCount: 3
  parameterServerType: standard
```

I use this command to submit the job:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
    --runtime-version 1.2 \
    --job-dir=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/train \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/train \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

After 10 mins to prepare, and next 20 minutes to run, the job logged some stranger infos `Error reported to Coordinator` and then out-of-memory error `The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 247`.

[image]

I checked the resource of this job and found out the Memory Utilization of master and all 5 workers were so high (approximately 90 - 95 %). But their CPUs Utilization were normal (60 - 65%).

I guess, I configured not enough memory for the trainer. But the question is how can I estimate to change the training input parameters? I mean how I know to change the `masterType` to higher level, or change `workerCount` to higher number, or decrease the `batch_size` in the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`? Is the image size related in this case?

I am confused now. Google cloud makes me poor so quick, so heuristic seems not affordable.

Comment: The Memory Utilization decreased from 95% to 70% when I decreased `batch_size` from 24 to 16. So, I think increase it to 20 is the best choice.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no good way to estimate memory utilization accurately in advance, but the trend is clear. For instance, if you decrease batch size, the memory needed will decrease too. You can try one configuration, and then adjust accordingly. One good news: we are increase the memory of GPU machines in couple of weeks, so you will be able to have larger batch size soon.

Comment: @Quoqing Xu, I am still confused about the image size. As I know, SSD resizes the image size into 300x300 px each dimension, but I don't know where that process happends, in the creating TFRecord file or the training job? If it in the training job process, then I have to resize image to smaller by myself to optimize the memory, am I right?